# Convert an array of flat objects to nested objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, nested

I have the following array, which is flattened, so I want to convert it to the nested array.

```
const data = [{
    "countryId": 9,
    "countryName": "Angola",
    "customerId": 516,
    "customerName": "CHEV",
    "fieldId": 2000006854,
    "fieldName": "A12"
},
{
    "countryId": 9,
    "countryName": "Angola",
    "customerId": 516,
    "customerName": "CHEV",
    "fieldId": 5037,
    "fieldName": "BANZ"
}
]
```

I would like to have the following interface

```
interface Option {
    value: number,
    viewText: string,
    ids?: Set<number>,
    children?: Option[]
}
```

So the output should look like this

```
const output = [{
    "value": 9,
    "viewText": "Angola",
    "ids": [516],
    "children": [{
        "value": 516,
        "viewText": "CHEV",
        "ids": [2000006854],
        "children": [{
            "viewText": "A12",
            "value": 2000006854
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I have been struggling with the solution, I don't know how to approach this, do I need to use a recursive function or something else, any ideas?

**Update:**

Here is my naive solution. The problem with this approach is that I'm manually handling nested structures.

```
function mapFlatToNested(data: typeof dataset) {
    const map = new Map<number, Option>()

    for (const item of data) {
        const itemFromMap = map.get(item.countryId);

        if (!itemFromMap) {
            map.set(item.countryId, {
                viewText: item.countryName,
                value: item.countryId,
                ids: new Set([item.customerId]),
                childrens: [{
                    viewText: item.customerName,
                    value: item.customerId,
                    ids: new Set([item.fieldId]),
                    childrens: [{
                        value: item.fieldId,
                        viewText: item.fieldName
                    }]
                }]
            })
        } else {
            if (!itemFromMap?.ids?.has(item.customerId)) {

                itemFromMap?.ids?.add(item.customerId);
                itemFromMap?.childrens?.push({
                    value: item.customerId,
                    viewText: item.customerName,
                    ids: new Set([item.fieldId]),
                    childrens: [{
                        value: item.fieldId,
                        viewText: item.fieldName
                    }]
                })

            } else {
                const customer = itemFromMap?.childrens?.find((customer) => customer.value === item.customerId);

                if (customer) {
                    if (!customer.ids?.has(item.fieldId)) {
                        customer.ids?.add(item.fieldId)
                        customer.childrens?.push({
                            value: item.fieldId,
                            viewText: item.fieldName,
                            ids: new Set([customer.value])
                        })
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return map
}

console.log(mapFlatToNested(dataset));
```

[Here is the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYmQbwChkTkA3OAGwFcIAuZEagWwCNoAaY0s4CAdwAqEAB5gGAZzBRQAcy6lkwACYSA-AwDKEMAB4mbaAD4FpBAAtglZVAgh1DDFlwBtALqEAvoUIJcU5GU4MDgJHWQAXmQXIkUAIj9qcCgATwBJZTiGAFYATlMSBOwk6RSAOThmCCzkOIBBSlloYDg4gtqEailsKqgMmoA2XLz2hK6wHugKqpr6gCEAUQAlABEFhbLkFaW0gBldtLKAcWRNAGEACVRUXeRdwRW27kKYPmt+hgAOAYAmAHZRq8INZptUGHFkHM6kc6mU4l4uLFSEUSqkPsgRs8OsVkuVKmDag0mjJWqNOt1euj-gBmAAMZPGkygoNmdTmAFUthc2WlkGdUABZAAKsIAmsgAGKoJZoMqaK5LBZoPZoIXLOqCNKoOVPeJA96ZBgDACM2U+gLeyhZ4Khc3hnkRWJRuPRmPiiVx1sJjWapKd5ImlMNyGpABZsgD-Yzel76kc0kLkABaZB1Xbx5aaXXI-XKdHDX4W4FW-GzXYLTRZhGEJGFD2lfNknGlWN1ECybCUP3u6PQV3GgYMilTUvgy4LABqS21yAAFJo6poOQBKZOp443OrZl6Wqm0-f7gafbKhosg0eE40-e2O93NtHB-L++94mbgtsdrvbjq9vrB7IDkOgYjm+tTjlOM7zouK5rrCRybt+cS5q6tLUpGeqWrGUJlAAWmmW5eIQHiEDASQIM4eDMHA6ASl2YCCNgZQQFIEDKLOQQhAwYApOgEDYDAgTBKEOirrWyB+PYYDIFR6CRIwAjIAK1H6Cw7BQBwaCYDgIBGLOy4+IoMDYFAc4SQEwCQMwyD8YJISiViihmVJFkQMwEpQD0SmyVEMkAHRNGAs4ucwvn1g+y4ANwGYopDAAJs4AITBe5nnUfZMUZdJ1G+WEgXBaFL4ZBpYmZTFvACMIYgMPlYWvhA7SlYoFA0PQSiWQVqLpMoDWNSQKgSAwIAKdogUuDVv4ZG4y49b1FhWDYdgDdEJW9WVfBCKI4hta5oW-qCM2rSQzW0NV7UBkyRUOYdsWqINw06LOY3tchyhTQdh1zdYtj2AwMRXddZVUCd20hS970A+Q62VVt+W5qC-3XZ4HgQ8gSMI4onj6aVnjIMCYQEOjsXxUllkpcwXlqL5-WU+YoRBWdE3KMu9mExlyUeeT1GU9TvlwMobHjcOf6RazMXs6l6CU59C32JT6BdOYs4rQDx2tYLwF-uDvXlRtVUg7tQv7aLpX9Xd-CnA9T07S9b3G5l0vfUtf0o6Vqundbu7dXb2tQ5t7ug5h+LezFaMo5j0W9TjeMoMrjVOeJv5yeLnOS6FlhfYtlOvCAbGzudvSrhERgJ0Lvmq5EERROrF1M1FwdxaZv7pS7fXE-n0BU6oNN07DnvMwTLcZe3UCd+ovP8-THvFhkWOD45v5p-NjtywrSvB4dbv62D6+rTr0P+75cP4lrLum-J5sjY9w9l0DEBTTvGXh3P3hh6L3gIy-pCfyQthgNQUCUWooRXw-hOwQF8pQbAshZwyVosEBiTEWJsQ4sJMAzM64gMktZagYB5ZSSiM7ZEqsahPniHvTarJ2ydm7MifqNQXAAQGG4Mk6cZYSHobHOIxCciAQRlw32YhZjgWnJsKCS52SrhTHBBCB04h0N+j8A8h5jyhmYXwh2i0OGi34RVCh74rzflKlw2+NRFFKKPCeD+yMv4eDRkAA)

Comment: Please share your attempt and explain where it fails.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, I have updated the question with my solution, please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Added the generic version.  It seems nicer overall, although not as targeted to the original problem.  The original answer is below.

### Generic Version

A more generic version of this idea would allow you to choose what input fields are keys, how they are transformed into output fields, and then what to do with the children.

Here is one implementation:

```js
const omit = (names) => (o) => 
  Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .filter (([k, v]) => !names .includes (k)))

const group = (fn) => (xs) =>
  Object .values (xs .reduce (
    (a, x, _, __, k = fn (x)) => ((a[k] = [... (a[k] || []), x]), a),
    {}
  ))

const nesting = (fields, descend) => (xs) => {
  const select = Object .entries (fields)
  const outers = select .map (([_, v]) => v)
  const descendents = Object .entries (descend)
  const makeKey = (x) => outers .map ((v) => x [v]) .join ('\u0000')
  return group (makeKey) (xs) .map ((group) => Object .assign (
    ... select .map (([k, v]) => ({[k]: group [0] [v]})),
    ... descendents .map (([k, v]) => ({[k]: v (group .map (omit (outers)))}))
  ))
}
    

const transform = nesting ({
  value: 'countryId', 
  viewText: 'countryName'
}, {
  ids: (xs) => xs .map (x => x.customerId),
  children: nesting ({
    value: 'customerId', 
    viewText: 'customerName',
  }, {
    ids: (xs) => xs .map (x => x.fieldId),
    // or: `children: (xs) => xs` to get all remaining fields intact.
    children: nesting ({
      value: 'fieldId', 
      viewText: 'fieldName'   
    }, {})
  })
})

const dataset = [{countryId: 59, countryName: "Algeria", customerId: 6959, customerName: "ABERDEEN DRILLING SCHOOL LTD", fieldId: 8627, fieldName: " BAGAN"}, {countryId: 59, countryName: "Algeria", customerId: 2730, customerName: "ABU DHABI COMPANY FOR ONSHORE OIL OPERATIONS", fieldId: 6158, fieldName: "BAB"}, {countryId: 59, countryName: "Algeria", customerId: 3457, customerName: "AGIP - ALGIERS", fieldId: 9562, fieldName: "LESS"}, {countryId: 9, countryName: "Angola", customerId: 516, customerName: "CHEVRON (SASBU) - ANGOLA", fieldId: 2000006854, fieldName: "A12"}, {countryId: 9, countryName: "Angola", customerId: 516, customerName: "CHEVRON (SASBU) - ANGOLA", fieldId: 5037, fieldName: "BANZALA"}]

console .log (transform (dataset))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We have two generic helper functions.  `omit` takes a list of keys and returns a function that takes an object and returns a clone that does not include those keys. `group` takes a key-generation function and returns a function that takes an array of values and groups them into arrays by the value returned by that key.

Our main function is `nesting`, and it takes two parameters:

- An object describing the fields that are used for grouping.  Its keys become the fields in the output, and its values are the properties from the input object; they are combined together to create the grouping key.  The output value is taken from the first element of the group.
- An object describing other fields that will be added.  Its keys again are the fields in the output, but its values are functions from the group to  some output field.  Here is where we handle recursion, simply making another call to `nested`.  But we can also do other things, such as pulling out all the child `id` into a single field as done here.

In this version, the omission of outer nodes is important, because most uses I've seen for something like this would involve grouping/nesting on a few levels, and then returning the remaining values intact.  We could do that by replacing our innermost `children` with an identity function.

### Original Version

This version lets you configure your function like this:

```
const transform = nestedGroup ('country', 'customer', 'field')
transform (dataset)
```

It's not particularly generic, embedding `'value'` and `'viewText'` inside the code, and making the assumption that the original fields look like `<something>Id` and `<something>Name`.  But it does the job, and subject to those restrictions, is configurable.

```js
const nestedGroup = (level, ...levels) => (xs, id = level + 'Id', name = level + 'Name') =>
  level == undefined 
    ? xs
    : Object .values (xs .reduce (
        (a, x, _, __, k = x [id] + '~' + x [name]) => ((a [k] = [... (a [k] || []), x]), a), 
        {}
      )) .map (xs => ({
        value: xs [0] [id], 
        viewText: xs [0] [name],
        ... (levels .length > 0 ? {
          ids: xs .map (x => x [`${levels [0]}Id`]),
          children: nestedGroup (...levels)(xs)
        } : {}),
      }))


const transform = nestedGroup ('country', 'customer', 'field')

const dataset = [{countryId: 59, countryName: "Algeria", customerId: 6959, customerName: "ABERDEEN DRILLING SCHOOL LTD", fieldId: 8627, fieldName: " BAGAN"}, {countryId: 59, countryName: "Algeria", customerId: 2730, customerName: "ABU DHABI COMPANY FOR ONSHORE OIL OPERATIONS", fieldId: 6158, fieldName: "BAB"}, {countryId: 59, countryName: "Algeria", customerId: 3457, customerName: "AGIP - ALGIERS", fieldId: 9562, fieldName: "LESS"}, {countryId: 9, countryName: "Angola", customerId: 516, customerName: "CHEVRON (SASBU) - ANGOLA", fieldId: 2000006854, fieldName: "A12"}, {countryId: 9, countryName: "Angola", customerId: 516, customerName: "CHEVRON (SASBU) - ANGOLA", fieldId: 5037, fieldName: "BANZALA"}]

console .log (transform (dataset))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start by creating, `id` and `name` values.  At the first level they will be `countryId` and `countryName`, then `customerId` and `customerName`, and so on.

Then, if we're at the bottom layer (no more levels to nest) we simply return our input.  Otherwise, we group together those values with the same `[id]` and `[name]` values, then for each group, we extract the common fields, as well as (if there's more nesting to do, the `ids` and, recursively, the `children`.

It would be interesting to make this much more generic.  I think it would be interesting to try to come up with a function that took this sort of configuration:

```
const transform = nestedGroup ('children', [
  {value: 'countryId', viewText: 'countryName', ['ids?']: (xs) => xs .map (x => x.id)},
  {value: 'customerId', viewText: 'customerName', ['ids?']: (xs) => xs .map (x => x.id)},
  {value: 'fieldId', viewText: 'fieldName', ['ids?']: (xs) => xs .map (x => x.id)},
])
```

where the `'?'` on `ids` marks it as optional: used only if there are further nested levels.  we could then write your transformation as an easy gloss that accepts `['country', 'customer', 'field']` and generates the above.  This would let us group on as many fields as we like and then rename them as we chose.  The first argument, , `'children'`, is just to allow us to name descendent nodes.  It would probably be better to include that per-level as well, but I don't have that quite figured out.

I think that would be an interesting and useful function, but I haven't worked out the details yet.  Perhaps I'll come back to it soon.

Comment: Thank you very impressive!
I think there is a bug in this line
`ids: xs.map(x => x [`${levels [1]}Id`])`, there should be `levels[0]`.


       Also  `children: nestedGroup (...levels) (xs .map (({[id]: v, [name]: t, ...rest}) => rest))`  I don't think we need to remove properties from the objects can be just 
`children: nestedGroup (...levels)(xs)`

Comment: But overall it works, I guess I will need some time to understand what is going on here. And what do you think is this logic performant? Will it run smoothly on 10k elements?

Comment: As to performance, I think you would have to test.  I don't think it's likely a problem.  It only nests as deeply as your hierarchy, so there should be no recursion problems.  Everything else should be fine.

Comment: You're right on both fixes.  `level[1]` was from an incomplete refactoring.  The other issue is based on thinking ahead to a more generic solution; it's unnecessary in this version.  I understand the more generic version now, but it will be some time before I can post it.  Both are now fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! It would be also cool if variables had more meaningful names :)

Comment: I suppose you could use `key` instead of `k`, but I see nothing more specific for `xs` or `x`.  Besides, https://degoes.net/articles/insufficiently-polymorphic

Comment: Added another version, more generic than the first.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to have one object instead of an array of objects?
Like key is going to be the id of item and the value is the item itself
And children also going to be an object. Just thinking how can I speed up nested item look up

Comment: That's probably for a new question.  But it's certainly doable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your array:

```
data.map(cur=>({
  value:cur.countryId,
    viewText:cur.countryName,
    ids:[cur.customerId],
    children:[{
        value:cur.customerId,
        viewText:cur.customerName,
        ids:[cur.fieldId],
        children:[{
            viewText:cur.fieldName,
            value:cur.fieldId
        }]
    }]
}))
```

Comment: It won't work because there is a possibility that each level of children can have more than one child